# nginx acessible from localhost but not from private ip

Tags: nginx, networking, localhost

I'm trying to expose an ubuntu computer to my local network to host a website.
After installing Nginx, and configuring ufw to open ports.

I configured Nginx with the following:

```
http{
  server{
     listen 80;
     location / 
     {
        root /home/fabioaraujo/Desktop/site;
     }
  }
}

events { }
```

If I visit my website via `localhost` it works ok.
However if I visit from another computer in the network, visiting my local IP address `https://192.168.1.12/` I get the following page.

(Can't post image)
Browser shows "404 page not found"

Can you help me to debug this?

Comment: Please add the output of `nginx -T` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that you have visited your private IP with https and not with http, maybe that is the error, since in the nginx file you specify port 80.